# jQuery end() issue

Tags: jquery

```
$licensetable
            .attr({
                'data-productkey': heritageProduct.genericProductKey,
                'data-internalid': heritageProduct.internalID
            }).find('.productname').text(heritageProduct.productName).siblings('.deletesystem').remove();

        $licensetable.find(':input').not(':button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Why does only the code above disable the input fields in `$licensetable`? Shouldnt the code below be eqvivalent?

```
$licensetable
            .attr({
                'data-productkey': heritageProduct.genericProductKey,
                'data-internalid': heritageProduct.internalID
            }).find('.productname').text(heritageProduct.productName).siblings('.deletesystem').remove().end().find(':input').not(':button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: You can try to use jQueryLog to check what is happening with your selectors www.jquerylog.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `.end()`:

```
$licensetable
    .attr({
        'data-productkey': heritageProduct.genericProductKey,
        'data-internalid': heritageProduct.internalID
    })
    .find('.productname').text(heritageProduct.productName)
    .siblings('.deletesystem').remove()
    .end()
    .end()
    .find(':input').not(':button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Docs for `.end()`: http://api.jquery.com/end

The first `.end()` gets you back to `$licensetable.find('.productname')` and the second one gets you back to `$licensetable`.

Comment: Is there any other methods that goes to the "top"? Similar to parent() vs closest()

Comment: In this case, since you have cached the selector in the `$licensetable`, it's probably just best to use `.end()` or go back to `$licensetable.find(':input').not(':button').prop('disabled', true);`. Using DOM traversal functions like `parents()` or `closest()` will create more overhead.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question. What i aksed for was a closest() version of end(). But anyway, thanks for helping :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery end documentation](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

> **Description:** End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

So, no, after your `end()` it will refer to the `$(.productname)`. Try `end().end()` (or refactor!).

Comment: Oh i see. Ill just disable them earlier then. I thought that end() always went to the "top". Thanks